# Vertical spacing (line height) with BigText

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement bigtext on a dynamic container. I get this to work with fittext neatly but I like the resizing of bigtext better.

Does anyone know how to prevent the text overlap with bigtext?

This is the bit of HTML test code:

```
<div id="fittextContainer" style="background-image: url({{=URL('static','images/tower.jpg')}})">
  <img class="imgTower" src="{{=URL('static','images/tower_.png')}}"/>
  <div id="fittext" class="containerText">
    Fittext. Make better decisions where location matters
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bigtextContainer" style="background-image: url({{=URL('static','images/tower.jpg')}})">
  <img class="imgTower" src="{{=URL('static','images/tower_.png')}}"/>
  <div id="bigtext" class="containerText">
    <span>BigText</span><span>Make better</span><span>decisions where location matters</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#fittextContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
}

#bigtextContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
}

.imgTower {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.containerText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #3f51b5;
}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this fuzzed out now. Line height needs to be set to normal and the page is game.

```
line-height: normal;
```

I previously removed the line-height property completely and assumed that normal would be the default value for line-height. But this doesn't seem to be the case. Or I might have changed the presumed default by using normalize CSS.

I also removed the height: auto instructions which are not required to make this work.

Here is the updated html:

```
    <div class="imgContainer" style="background-image: url({{=URL('static','images/tower.jpg')}})">
        <img class="imgTransparent" src="{{=URL('static','images/tower_.png')}}"/>
        <div id="fittext" class="containerText">Make better decisions where location matters</div>
    </div>


    <div class="imgContainer" style="background-image: url({{=URL('static','images/tower.jpg')}})">
        <img class="imgTransparent" src="{{=URL('static','images/tower_.png')}}"/>
        <div id="bigtext" class="containerText"><span>Make better</span><span>decisions where location matters</span></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the updated CSS:

```
.imgContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.imgTransparent {
    width: 100%;
}

.containerText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #3f51b5;
}
```

Here is the result (fittext on top):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hi There.** It's difficult to test it for myself because I don't have the measures of your image (It would be nice if you could write it down). First of all, I would recommend you to integrate the image in the div with the css line:

```
background-image: url();
```

You can also try to use some padding and don't use a solid value (like x em) or something sometimes instead of auto. Auto messes many things up in my experience.

Cheers,
Daniel.

Comment: I do use the background-image css property with cover. The image item inside the container is transparent with the same size of the background image in order to preserve the height of the container when resizing the object.